# How to do the live stream using CameraX Jetpack Library in Android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to do a live stream that shows on my subscribers. I found some libraries but that all libraries more than 4 years old. And, I am a little bit familiar with the cameraX library of Jetpack it is a great library and I want to use this in our application.

So, Is it possible to host a live stream using cameraX library, and if is it yes, So could you please give me some idea, how?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks